# BATCH - Better way to copy single folder from multiple directories

Tags: batch-file

I have built a batch backup program for work. It also has the capability to restore the data to computer.

Originally I had robocopy exclude appdata and just grab outlook files seperately. Recently I have found I want to grab all the appdata but put it into a seperate folder. 
My challenge is I want to grab Appdata from all users on the computer, not just the current user.
I know I can just discover all folders in C:\Users and then copy appdata folders in a for loop, but I feel like there has to be a better, cleaner way to do it.

Currently I would be doing something like this:
(This is not working code, its just the idea I want to make cleaner)

```
For /f %%a in ('dir C:\Users /B /A D') do (
   robocopy "C:\Users\%%a" "BACKUP DIR\AppData"
)
```

I would love for a solution more like the exclusion method

```
robocopy "C:\Users" "BACKUP DIR\AppData" /only folders named appdata
```

Comment: `Robocopy` has a `/S` option.

Comment: Doesn't that just make it from copy all sub directories?
I want to grab only appdata from all users in C:\Users

Comment: There aren't likely to be many files in the top level of your AppData directories, but if that's what you wanted then I apologise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check if the user has an appdata dir and copy it.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "C:\Users"') do (
  if exist C:\Users\%%a\Appdata robocopy c:\Users\%%a\Appdata\ D:\BACKUP\
)
```

You probably need to also do `if not exist backup mkdir backup` if each user will have his/her own backup dir.

Comment: Tested this today and ended up in an infinite loop. 
`for /f %%a in ('dir "C:\Users" /B /A D') do if exist "C:\Users\%%a\Appdata" robocopy c:\Users\%%a\Appdata\ F:\BACKUP\%%a\ /s`

Comment: Your's didnt work, so I made it at least work. I am running it as a batch program so %a doesn't work. putting `"C:\Users"` first ended up with:

`0    c:\Users\Default\Appdata\Local\Application Data\
0    c:\Users\Default\Appdata\Local\Application Data\Application Data`

Which doesn't exist.
My edits allowed the code to run and copy, but instead of copying 50GB's, it kept going and I cancelled when it reached 70GB's

Comment: it was the missing `:` in `/a:d` in my version of the code. It is now appears to be working without looping.

Comment: Why would this code work on Win 10 but then not on win 7?

Comment: @garyallen What do you mean by does not work? What is the output or error?

Comment: No error but it keeps making a directory within a directory indefinitely. Had to format the test drive to delete it.
d:\backup\appdata\application data\application data\application data\application data\application data\application data\application data\application data and onwards...

Comment: Will have to simulate it and see why. Will get back to you.